# How to set the Stack segment

Tags: assembly

Can some one help understand the how to set the stack for the OS.

As far as I understood, the SS is to be set by the "programmer" to 1024 (1k) and move the SP to the top of it, is that correct?

and I found the below on MikeOS tutorial, not sure how adding 544 to 07c0 will add 4k buffer

```
bootloader_start:

    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Set up 4K of stack space above buffer

    add ax, 544         ; 8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough for a meaningful answer. The code you've shown just loads a value into AX, then adds another value to it. You end up with a value in AX, but have done nothing to affect the stack at all. What you have right now is equivalent to `mov ax, 09eoh`, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to set the stack segment.

```
; NASM syntax
xor ax, ax ; or set ax to whatever segment you wish
mov ss, ax ; IIRC, you can't just go mov ss, 0
mov sp, 0xF000 ; or set sp to whatever you wish
```

I don't think I had to put the stack there. You can put it wherever you want, as long as you don't overwrite system data.

Comment: I've forgot to put the rest of the code please find it below     mov ax, 07C0h   ; Set up 4K of stack space above buffer

 add ax, 544   ; 8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs (loader)

 cli    ; Disable interrupts while changing stack

 mov ss, ax

 mov sp, 4096

Comment: In other words, How to set the SS?

Comment: I already told you how to set the SS. Here it is again: `mov ss, ax`

Comment: I believe you need to mask interrupts while setting the `ss` and `sp`